# Why the given code is not converting any text to uppercase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script> 
var a = document.getElementById("text").value;
function toupper()
{
    var mystring = new String(a);
    document.write(a.toUpperCase());
}
</script>

**HTML**
<input type="text" id="text" name="text" />
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="clickme" name="click" onclick="toupper();"/>
```

Why the variable "a" cannot be accessed in the "toupper" function?

Comment: Um, `mystring.toUpperCase()`?

Comment: `a` is already a string

Answer (score 1):

Pull `var a` inside the function & you don't have to write `new String(a)`

```
function toupper() {
    var a = document.getElementById("text").value;
    document.write(a.toUpperCase());
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fn4Ns/3/

Answer (score 0):

The execution of the statement `var a = document.getElementById("text").value` fails, because when it is executed, the element with `id` value of `text` has not been parsed, i.e. does not exist. You need to have `document.getElementById("text")` inside the function, or otherwise at a point where the element exists.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are trying to execute

```
var a = document.getElementById("text").value;
```

before the document finished loading.

please try the following it should work.

```
var a;
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            a = document.getElementById("text").value;     
        });

        function toupper()
        {
            var mystring = new String(a);
            document.write(a.toUpperCase());
        }
```

Variable a is declared outside so it's accessible in both scopes callback for document ready and toupper function.
Get the element value, after you make sure the page (DOM) has been loaded

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-retrieve the reference to the text field on every function call.

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UB3v2/)</kbd>

```
var writeNewLine = function(text) {
    var addChild = function(node) {
        window.document.body.appendChild(node);
    };
    addChild(document.createElement('br'));
    addChild(document.createTextNode(text.toUpperCase()));
};

window.toupper = function() {
    var mystring = document.getElementById("text").value;
    writeNewLine(mystring.toUpperCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. you assigned value before text boxes has loaded

`function toupper(){
    var a = document.getElementById("text").value;
    document.write(a.toUpperCase());
}`